# compare data from two worksheets based on values of column a column d

Tags: excel, vba

i am looking to find a vba code that loops through all rows in sheet1 looking for matches of data based on colmn a and column d values in sheet1 being found matched in column a and column d in sheet2. example column a 1011 column d john. if somewhere in sheet2 column a = 1011 and column d same row = john then match found. I need to save all non matches to a new workbook.

Comment: It is looking for Orphans in sheet1 that are not in sheet2 ??  Or Orphans in sheet2 that are not in sheet1 ??  What is the approx row count of each sheet?

Comment: yes it is looking for orphans in sheet1 that are not in sheet2

Comment: `=countifs(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$5000, A1, Sheet2!$D$1:$D$5000, D1)>=1` Stick that in Sheet1!E1 and copy down and it will give you a true/false output if there is a match. No need for VBA here.

Comment: i import the database from a csv each week , then check for changes , so did hope to use vba instead of having to add formula. plus i needed orphans from sheet1 saved to another workbook

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  It put the result in Sheet3 of this workbook. >>

```
Option Explicit  '  it is your friend

Sub do_FindOrphans()

'   create or find Sheet3, and clear it out
    If Not Evaluate("ISREF('Sheet3'!A1)") Then
        Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet3"
    Else
        Sheets("Sheet3").Activate
    End If
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents

'   initialize max row#, and copy in column headings
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Dim s1row As Long, s1max As Long, s1col As Long, s1endcol As Integer
    s1max = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Dim s2row As Long, s2max As Long
    s2max = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim s3row As Long, matched As String

    With ActiveSheet
        s1endcol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With
    s3row = 1
    For s1col = 1 To s1endcol
        Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(s3row, s1col) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, s1col)
    Next s1col

'   step thru sheet1
    For s1row = 2 To s1max
        matched = "N"
'       step thru sheet2
        For s2row = 2 To s2max
'           Compare the keys
            If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, s1row) = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, s2row) _
            And Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, s1row) = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(4, s2row) Then
                matched = "Y"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next s2row
        If matched = "N" Then
            s3row = s3row + 1
            For s1col = 1 To s1endcol
                Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(s3row, s1col) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(s1row, s1col)
            Next s1col
        End If
    Next s1row

End Sub
```